# Can no longer open android app (until reinstall)

Tags: android, xamarin, logcat

I've been having reports from users saying that they can no longer open our app; and I have now seen this on my own phone.

When I tap the app icon the screen goes black (showing the title but that's it), then quickly the black screen disappears and you're back in the OS.

Logcat shows zero issues when this happens.

Anyone know what could be happening? This issue has only become apparent within the last few weeks before that there were no reports from users on this particular issue.

EDIT: I've tried restarting the phone, force-stopping the app and clearing the cache+data to no avail.

Comment: does your app use Internet at it's launch ?

Comment: @Le-roy: Tried to implement ACRA (Application Crash Report for Android) in your app to see if it picks up any anomaly with your app. ACRA can be downloaded from [here](http://acra.ch/).

Comment: @ChuongPham I'm using something similar (raygun.io) but it doesn't report anything. I would have thought I'd see something in logcat if it was a 'reportable' error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about `raygun.io`, but I know ACRA traps most of the unforseen errors - the exception is certain Reflection methods are sometimes not caught by ACRA. Overall, ACRA is not too bad.

Comment: User could also capture bug report of he/she is advanced enough. I am sure there has to be a clue in there. Said that, what are you doing at start?

Comment: There can be many reasons for such crash, I think an infinite loop would cause something like that for example. First can you run the app in debug and reproduce the crash? If so that would give you a direction where the issue first appears. Second, what events you subscribed on for unhandled/unobserved/(java)uncaught exceptions, you might not see an error report if you're missing one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If your app having use internet or http request over network then write code in method  onResume otherwise for http request use asynchronous task

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am using http requests but they are in a background service which shouldn't affect the UI should it? Besides it isn't getting called when the app loads.